# javascript switch() giving the default value?

Tags: javascript, html, input, switch-statement

why is this code only giving me the default value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id= "demo"></p>
<input id="age" />
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=text">try it</button>

<script>
var text;
age = document.getElementById('age').value;
switch (age) {
  case 10:
    text = "diuble";
    break;
  case 13:
    text = "puberty";
    break;
  case 18:
    text = "Beer!";
    break;
  default:
    text = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing document.getElementById('age').value to 18, when i do that it gives me the output as beer! but right now its only giving me Looking Forward....

Comment: `document.getElementById('age').value` im pretty sure this gives a string, your switch cases are number so they dont match. and `<input id="age" />` doesnt have a value

Comment: because the code only runs on the page load.... It does not magically keep running. That is what event handlers are for.

Comment: Asd a plus sign in front of `document.getElementById('age').value` To confer it to a number.

Comment: @Akxe needs a lot more than a `+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling a function `onclick`, and firing the code on document load. The right way to do it would be:

```js
function getText(){
          var text;
          age = document.getElementById('age').value;
          age = parseInt(age)
          switch (age) {
               case 10:
                    text = "diuble";
                    break;
               case 13:
                    text = "puberty";
                    break;
               case 18:
                    text = "Beer!";
                    break;
               default:
                    text = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
          }
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=text
}
```

```html
<p id= "demo"></p>
<input id="age" />
<button onclick="getText()">try it</button>
```